# Why is the jplayer not playing song

Tags: javascript, html, jplayer

Here is my jplayer code

```
<div id="player"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#player").jPlayer( {
    ready: function () {
      $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
        mp3: '/bedupako/songs_related/uploads/1.mp3' // Defines the url
      }).jPlayer("play"); // Attempts to Auto-Play the media
    },
    supplied: "mp3",
    swfPath: "js"
  });
```

and i am sure that my mp3 path is correct, also i am sure of the `swfpath` too. So why my song being not played?

**EDIT:**

Ok now i just got frstrated and just did this. I got the DEMO jPlayer, the [simple circle](http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-05/) and just uploaded it on my site. With only the following changes:

circle.player.js got the following changes

```
solution: "html", // I want only HTML5 playback, NO FLASH
supplied: "mp3",
```

in Index.php. I removed the second players and then changed the constructor of one of them to the following

```
var myCirclePlayer = new CirclePlayer("#jquery_jplayer_1",
            {
                mp3: "http://bedupako.com/songs_related/uploads/40.mp3"
            }, {
                cssSelectorAncestor: "#cp_container_1"
            });
```

And the live link is [here](http://bedupako.com/songs_related/SimpleHtmlCirclePlayer/). I am specifically using HTML5 player as i need that. (**In Opera and firefox**, chrome played my song; havent tried in IE, but honestly i dont care about IE anyway :P cos there is always some problem with it -_-) *please disable your flash plugin before playing it*

Comment: Any error messages or anything?

Comment: Have you got a link to a live page when we can see your implementation?

Comment: I have edited the question, please see it.

Comment: Your mp3 paths are completely different in your original question and your edit.

Comment: @Vigrond yep, thats not a mistake, Both mp3s do exist, so that shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither Firefox nor Opera support the MP3 format in HTML 5 Audio, only WEBMA and OGA:

> ```
> HTML5 browsers and their supported audio file formats:
>
> Firefox (OSX, Win): WEBMA, OGA
> Safari (OSX, Win): MP3, M4A
> Mobile Safari iOS4 (iPad, iPhone, iPod): MP3, M4A
> Opera (OSX, Win): WEBMA, OGA
> Chrome (OSX, Win): WEBMA, OGA, MP3, M4A
> IE9 (Win): MP3, M4A (Can install the WebM codec.)
> ```

taken from http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#reference-html5-audio-format

Comment: Omg, Here IE9 scores over firefox. I mean the most used mp3 format is not supported by it??? Bad. But anyway thanks :)

Comment: I was surprised when i first found out, too.. Maybe they know something we don't? (that MP3 won't last)

Comment: OGG is under GPL license while MP3 is not.  Many organizations claim ownership of patents relating to MP3 - therefore may sue anything they deem scrutinable.  More info here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3#Licensing_and_patent_issues

Answer (score 2):

do you get any `error` or `warning` alerts if you add the following two constructor options?

```
$("#player").jPlayer( {
    ready: function () {
      $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
        mp3: '/bedupako/songs_related/uploads/1.mp3' // Defines the url
      }).jPlayer("play"); // Attempts to Auto-Play the media
    },
    supplied: "mp3",
    swfPath: "js",
    errorAlerts: true,
    warningAlerts: true
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a short example, describing the code and directory structure on my blog here: http://vigrond.com/blog/2011/12/01/invisible-html5-flash-audio-player-using-jplayer/ (Click the link to the example)

Hopefully you can compare your code to this and see the problem.

It is hard to say what is causing the problem without a live test page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an absolute path for your mp3 file?